# Mac 'adb push' command only works on one of my USB ports

Tags: android, macos, usb, adb

What makes only one USB port work for transferring a file from a mac to an android phone with adb by USB cable?

When I run 'adb push file.mp3 storage/self/primary/Download' while I use the USB port on the right side of the computer, everything works. If I use the left USB port, I get a variety of errors like:

'''
adb: error: failed to copy 'file.mp3' to 'storage/self/primary/Download/file.mp3': couldn't read from device
file.mp3: 0 files pushed. 361.9 MB/s (982920 bytes in 0.003s)
'''

'''
adb: error: failed to get feature set: device offline
'''

'''
adb: error: 8-byte write failed: Protocol wrong type for socket
'''

How can I make either USB port work? I'm wondering if this is some USB driver only being installed on one of the controllers or something like that.

I installed Android Platform Tools and connected a Goggle Pixel 2 XL by USB type A on the laptop to the USB C phone port with a single cable (no adapters). Running 'adb devices' shows the phone as connected and I have developer mode set on the phone (I used this phone for android development with lots of adb install, uninstall, logcat, etc commands).

I installed adb with 'brew cask install android-platform-tools' and I have been using brew for other programs with no problems etc.

My PATH is set to use the brew version of adb instead of the android studio version (and I confirmed this by checking the versions used by each).

On a macbook pro early 2015 running 10.12.6 (macOS Sierra).

Thanks!

Comment: Not only Mac, also happens on Linux. It drove me crazy: different errors, also "can't write to device: EOF". But when I saw your question I tried another port and it works now! It worked for many months with the other port. Unbelievable!

Answer (score 2):

Amazingly, changing the USB port to which the device was connected to my Mac solved the issue... so weird.

Comment: what do you mean? "changing the USB port"? do you mean we can specify the port for adb command? The command "ioreg -p IOUSB -w0 -l" can tell "the port which the devices was connected to".

Comment: I tried several times from the same port (connected to a hub) and it didn't help. Only when i switched to PC USB directly it copied the file. So Strange since other files copied correctly